# Jquery - Position Top Left of Screen

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I how can I get this child div to sit at the top left of the screen no matter what the screen resolution is using jQuery?

```
<div style="position: relative; margin: auto; width: 500px">

    <div style="position: absolute;></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tmr4p/

The solution need to be compatible with IE.

Comment: `fixed` is the correct value to use (see DAVIEAC's answer). Using `absolute` will only position it relative to the first non-static ancestor, such as your parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
position:fixed

top:0;
left:0;
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"></div>
```

or fixed if you arent refering to the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Checked for IE and Chrome(for the time), [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tmr4p/1/).

Based on given answers of this chain.